# iPhone camera in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is there a way to test code using iPhone camera in the simulator?

(Somebody must have written something - you could have a replacement component that simulates the camera)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simulator there are some sample photo library images that you can access.

Use: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary

Comment: I though you could have made a test-version by deriving from UIImagePickerControlle, but I read in the docs it cant be exended

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your actual camera API usage, you would have to closely emulate a fairly large non-trivial portion of the AVFoundation framework.

If you just want to test the rest of your app, you could just ifdef out all the camera related stuff and replace your image capture and preview data with a static png.